# Memberships renewal report using a left join on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables:

```
Member
'id'
'name'

Membership
'id'
'site_id'
'member_id'
'year'
```

I'd like to set up a report to keep track of subscriptions during years like so:

1. Site-id
2. total 2019 subscription
3. total 2018 subscription
4. NEW (first-time subscription to that site)
5. Renewal (subs in 2019 and in 2018 at the same site)
6. Lost (subs done in 2018 but not in 2019 to that site)

I'm struggling around two left join on the same `Membership` table like so:

```
SELECT m.site_id, 
count(m2019.id) as total2019, 
count(m2018.id) as total2018, 
SUM(IF(m2019.member_id IS NOT NULL AND m2018.member_id IS NULL, 1, 0)) new, 
SUM(IF(m2019.member_id IS NOT NULL AND m2018.member_id IS NOT NULL AND m2018.site_id = m2019.site_id, 1, 0)) renewal, 
SUM(IF(m2018.member_id IS NOT NULL AND m2019.member_id IS NULL, 1, 0)) lost 
FROM membership m 
LEFT JOIN membership m2019 ON m.id = m2019.member_id AND m.year = '2019' AND m2019.year = '2019' AND m.site_id = m2019.site_id 
LEFT JOIN membership m2018 ON m.id= m2018.member_id AND m.year = '2018' AND m2018.year = '2018' AND m.site_id = m2018.site_id 
GROUP BY m.site_id;
```

counts are correct but the conditions are not so I'm pretty sure my query is not correct.
I'm on it since long time and I start feeling kind of lost.

Could anyone help me figuring out where I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you want with two levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT m.site_id, 
       SUM( m.max_year = 2019 ) as total2019, 
       SUM( m.min_year = 2018 ) as total2018,
       SUM( m.min_year = 2019 AND m.max_year = 2019 ) as new2019,
       SUM( m.min_year = 2018 and m.max_year = 2018 ) as renewals,
       SUM( m.max_year = 2018 ) as lost
FROM (SELECT m.id, m.site_id, MIN(year) as min_year, MAX(year) as max_year
      FROM membership m
      WHERE year in (2018, 2019)
      GROUP BY m.id, m.site_id
     ) mm
     ON mm.id = m.id
GROUP BY m.site_id;
```

Comment: That was what i need. Thank you